# Connecting new drain/overflow drain assembly using coupling

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

I recently purchased a old house and I have had constant problems with the tub clogging.  In the past I was able to snake it successfully but this time the snake seems to have gotten stuck and when I tried to push it past I separated the connection where the pipe for the tub drain meets the pipe for the overflow.  I have gotten prices but right now it will take a while to get it fixed.  Looking at the connection I'm not sure if I could temporarily fix it using a flexible coupling.

The idea I had to fix it if just a coupling didn't work seemed a little involved but some what possible.  Apparently there is at least a couple of feet before the trap (this may be the cause of the constant blockage).  My thought is I could just replace the whole drain assembly and then use a coupling to connected the drain assembly to the rest of the pipe that goes to the trap.  I'm thinking this would hold until I can get it permanently fixed.

Is this a bad idea as a fix,  I have to replace the drain assembly anyway as part of the permanent fix and they generally go for about sixty dollars from what I can see.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You have access to the drain assembly through an access panel, or hole you cut in the wall, or something?

Comment: I have an access panel behind it and the rest goes through my garage.  Due to the initial leak this caused I had to remove the drywall and insulation below it, so I also have access from below.